# Why is my RxJS countdown clock not displaying?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on an Angular 9 quiz app and I'm using RxJS for the countdown timer (in containers\scoreboard\time\time.component.ts) and the timer doesn't seem to be displaying. The stopTimer() function should stop the timer on the number of seconds on which it is stopped. The timer should stop after the correct answer(s) are selected and the timer should reset in between questions. The time elapsed per question should be saved into the elapsedTimes array. Please see my code for the timer in the TimeComponent on Stackblitz: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app**. Thank you.

The code below is my first start with building a countdown clock with RxJS. My most recent code is on Stackblitz.

```
  countdownClock() {
    this.timer = interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.isPause),
        takeUntil(this.isStop)
      );
    this.timerObserver = {
      next: (_: number) => {
        this.timePerQuestion -= 1;
          ...
        }
    };

    this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);
  }

  goOn() {
    this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);
  }

  pauseTimer() {
    this.isPause.next();
    // setTimeout(() => this.goOn(), 1000)
  }

  stopTimer() {
    this.timePerQuestion = 0;
    this.isStop.next();
  }
```

I use stopTimer() and pauseTimer() in my TimerService so I can call them from a different component.

Comment: Put a [mre] *in the question*.

Comment: can you write in words what your requirements are?

Comment: Yes I would like the countdown clock to decrease from 20 seconds to 0 seconds. When the correct answer(s) is/are selected, the clock should stop on the amount of seconds left and the elapsed time per question should be saved in the elapsedTimes array for calculating total completion time later. For each following question the clock should reset to 20 seconds. The user's answers for each question and the time elapsed should be stored in its own array (using the Result interface) and passed to the ResultsComponent.

Comment: Stuck getting the countdown clock to work. Can someone help?

Comment: fixed your stackblitz by forking a new one from yours. find my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have fixed your stackblitz. Based on your call of timerservice methods, your timer will behave

And no need to set elapsed time in teardown logic. it will automatically push whenver timer will stop.

Stackblitz Url :- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-quiz-app-er3pjn

Time countdown method :-

```
  countdownClock() {
    const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
    const start$ = this.timerService.isStart.asObservable().pipe(shareReplay(1));
    const reset$ = this.timerService.isReset.asObservable();
    const stop$ = this.timerService.isStop.asObservable();
    const markTimestamp$ = fromEvent($("#mark"), "click");
    const continueFromLastTimestamp$ = fromEvent($("#continue"), "click");
    start$.subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
    this.timeLeft$ = concat(start$.pipe(first()), reset$).pipe(
      switchMapTo(
        timer(0, 1000).pipe(
          scan((acc, crt) => acc > 0? acc - 1: acc, this.timePerQuestion),
        )
      ),
      takeUntil(stop$.pipe(skip(1))),
      repeatWhen(completeSbj =>
        completeSbj.pipe(
          switchMapTo(
            start$.pipe(
              skip(1),
              first()
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ).pipe(tap((value)=>this.timerService.setElapsed(this.timePerQuestion-value)));
```

In scoreboard component params subscribe i have reset the timer, so it will reset whenever question will change.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the time to run continuous once the question route is reached for each new question the time should start from 20 seconds. Also when the correct answer(s) are selected the time should stop. Not sure I know how to replace button observables with subjects. I shouldn't need to display the buttons in the UI.

Comment: Also not sure how to integrate the logic from the "myTearDownLogic" function that follows.

Comment: @integral100x updated the solution with new stackblitz. please check. please read whole solution again.

Comment: Great, thank you! I have console.logged the elapsedTimes array in the ResultsComponent but am getting duplicate values for the times and completionTime is undefined. I updated my Stackblitz.

Comment: If the time gets below 10 seconds, there should be a 0 before the timeLeft, i've tried   <span class="scoreboard" i18n>
    0:<span *ngIf="timeLeft < 10">0</span>{{ timeLeft$ | async }}
  </span> and timeLeft = Number($timeLeft) in the ts file

Comment: Hello @integral100x, i have fixed remaining issues. please find above the updated stackblitz url. hope it helped.

Answer (score 6):

As with every complex problem, you have to break it into smaller, digestible problems.

Therefore, I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-pjytrb?file=index.ts) demo that recreates the basic functionalities:

- start a timer
- stop temporarily (mark timestamp); for example when all answers would be selected
- continue from the last timestamp
- reset timer
- stop timer

Here's the code for this:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

const start$ = fromEvent($('#start'), 'click').pipe(shareReplay(1));
const reset$ = fromEvent($('#reset'), 'click');
const stop$ = fromEvent($('#stop'), 'click');
const markTimestamp$ = fromEvent($('#mark'), 'click');
const continueFromLastTimestamp$ = fromEvent($('#continue'), 'click');

const src$ = concat(
  start$.pipe(first()),
  reset$
).pipe(
  switchMapTo(
    timer(0, 1000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(markTimestamp$),
        repeatWhen(
          completeSbj => completeSbj.pipe(switchMapTo(
            continueFromLastTimestamp$.pipe(first())
          ))
        ),
        scan((acc, crt) => acc + 1000, 0)
      )
  ),
  takeUntil(stop$),
  repeatWhen(completeSbj => completeSbj.pipe(switchMapTo(start$.pipe(skip(1), first()))))
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Let's go through each relevant part.

---

```js
concat(
  start$.pipe(first()),
  reset$
).pipe(switchMapTo(timer(...)))
```

The `timer` will start to count from 0 only if it hasn't started before(`start$.pipe(first())`) or the user wants to reset everything(`reset$`).

`concat(a$, b$)` makes sure that that `b$` can't emit unless `a$` completes.

---

```js
timer(0, 1000)
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(markTimestamp$),
    repeatWhen(
      completeSbj => completeSbj.pipe(switchMapTo(
        continueFromLastTimestamp$.pipe(first())
      ))
    ),
    scan((acc, crt) => acc + 1000, 0)
  )
```

We want the timer to be active until `markTimestamp$` emits. When this happens, the source(`timer(0, 1000)`) will be unsubscribed. With `repeatWhen` we can decide when should the `timer` be resubscribed. That is, when `continueFromLastTimestamp$.pipe(first())` emits. It's important that we use `first()`, otherwise the source might be re-subscribed multiple times.

Placing `scan((acc, crt) => acc + 1000, 0)` after `repeatWhen` ensures that the last timestamp won't be lost. For example, the timer might start at `X`, at `X+5` the user triggers `markTimestamp$` and then at `X + 100` the user triggers `continueFromLastTimestamp$`. What this happens, the timer will emit `X+6`.

---

```js
takeUntil(stop$),
repeatWhen(completeSbj => completeSbj.pipe(switchMapTo(start$.pipe(skip(1), first()))))
```

The timer should be active until `stop$` emits. Then, it can restart only if the user triggers `start$` again. `skip(1)` is used because we don't the cached value by the `ReplaySubject` used by `start$`'s `shareReplay` and `first()` is used because the **source** should be **re-subscribed** **only once**.

---

Comment: Okay, I've added the code to my TimerComponent, but not sure how to make this work in my app... Timer doesn't decrease and not sure how to make the timer stop for the correct answer and don't think I need to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: My intention with the code above was to provide something to build upon, or at least an idea. For example, if you want the timer to decrease, add the max value to the scan’s second parameter and in the cb function decrease with the amount you want. You may want to stop the timer if all the correct answers are selected, meaning you could have an obs that will emit when that happens.

Comment: So scan would look like: scan((acc, crt) => acc - 1000, 20000)? Not sure how to bind the observer to the template.

Comment: I tried: <div class="time-left">
  <label class="leader" i18n>Time</label>
  <span class="scoreboard" i18n>
    0:{{ src$ | async }}
  </span>
</div> saying that Property 'src$' does not exist on type 'TimerComponent'.

Comment: I'm getting these errors in the console: ERROR TypeError: Invalid event target AND Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

Comment: The async pipe must be given a promise or an observable, but you it seems like you've passed an object.

Comment: I've declared src$: Observable<any> in the TimerComponent class; and then used this.src$ = concat(...) but getting error TS2740: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<any>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.

Comment: I removed .subscribe() and that error went away, but still not passing the right value to the async pipe.

Comment: Ok I added .subscribe(console.log) back after the .pipe() and const before the src$, not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I tried this: const timeObs = of(src$);
    this.timeLeft$ = timeObs;
    this.timeLeft = Number(this.timeLeft$); getting 0:20 in the view using {{timeLeft}}, doesn't seem to decrement, can't figure out how to convert from Observable<Subscription> to Observable<number>

Comment: I wrapped the concat(...) inside of() and set this.timeLeft$ = src$, and getting [object Object] error when I run the code.

Comment: Can anyone help? Still stuck.