# In Rxjs How to pause a stream of data and continue from the second It was paused?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive, rxjs6

I have a stream of data being long polled every 10 seconds. Long pol can be **paused** and be **continued**.

**Problem is**: It starts over when It continues. I have to make It continue from the second It was paused.

So if:

**delay(10000)**

**paused at (7000)**

Then when I start the long polling again my data has to be pulled after (10000-7000)=**3000**

Today is the **fourth day** I have been stuck with this problem and going insane..

I have created this blitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang7-working-rxjs-stream-timer-combined?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Created a flow and a timer which pulls data. When flow and timer stops, sets the time that was left along with the new delay. But still when I press start It doesnt wait 3 more seconds It just cals the service right away which I dont want

Comment: Could you split 10s into eg. 10 smaller 1s delays?

Comment: https://medium.com/js-in-action/rxjs-pause-and-resume-mighty-switchmap-41d0d1fe1113

Comment: Take a look at "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676617/pause-an-interval-rxjs" same problem, just as a stopwatch :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an extremely rudimentary implementation relying on `timer` function and `take`, `filter` and `takeUntil` operators.

The solution in my view isn't too elegant. It depends on state variables `paused` and `first` and has a recursive trigger inside the `next` callback in the subscription. Also note it doesn't at the moment do any error handling. The polling completely stops in that case.

Controller

```js
export const REFRESH_INTERVAL = 11;

@Component({ ... })
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  pause$ = new Subject();
  reset$ = new Subject();
  closed$ = new Subject();
  counter = REFRESH_INTERVAL;
  res: any;
  paused = false;

  constructor(private freeApiService: freeApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    let first = true;
    this.reset$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(_ =>
          timer(0, 1000).pipe(
            take(this.counter),
            tap(_ => (this.paused = this.paused ? false : this.paused)),
            takeUntil(this.pause$),
            filter(_ => first || --this.counter === 0),
            finalize(
              () => (this.paused = this.counter != 0 ? true : this.paused)
            ),
            switchMap(_ => this.freeApiService.getDummy())
          )
        ),
        takeUntil(this.closed$)
      )
      .subscribe({
        next: res => {
          first = false;
          this.res = res;
          this.counter = REFRESH_INTERVAL;
          this.reset$.next();
        },
        error: error => console.log("Error fethcing data:", error)
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.closed$.next();
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div my-app>
    <ng-container *ngIf="res; else noRes">
        <button (mouseup)="paused ? reset$.next() : pause$.next()">
      {{ paused ? 'Resume poll' : 'Pause poll' }}
    </button>

        <br><br>
        Refreshing in: {{ counter }}
        <br>
    Response:
        <pre>{{ res | json }}</pre>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #noRes>
        <button (mouseup)="reset$.next()">
      Start poll
    </button>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ang7-working-rxjs-stream-timer-combined-1grksw?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: This is really great! Thank you so much! A quick question; Would this approach cause memory leakage besides making sure to subscribe only once?

Comment: The `takeUntil(this.closed$)` should in theory closed the open subscription when the component is closed. So I'd say no, it wouldn't cause any memory leak.

Comment: If I use a slow responding api endpoint to this code. It repeats the request until one of them resolves and that is what I wanted to prevent in the first place. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the combination of `interval`, `filter` and `scan` operators with check frequency being set to 1s:

```js
const pauserSubject = new BehaviorSubject(true);

const s$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  withLatestFrom(pauserSubject),
  filter(([intervalValue, isAllowed]) => isAllowed),
  scan(acc => acc + 1, 0),
  tap(emissionNumber => console.log('check attempt #', emissionNumber, ' on ', new Date().toTimeString())),
  filter(emissionCount => !(emissionCount % 10)),
  switchMapTo(of('request/response'))
);
```

[Stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pausable-stream?file=index.ts)

In this case the regular `interval` sets the "beat" checking the pause being true or false every 1s. After it's unpaused, the corresponding `filter` operator allows to proceed. The `scan` verifies that every 10th check (or every 10th second) will result a http call.

For your scenario:

1. You start polling every 10 seconds
2. You pause at the 3rd second for one second long
3. The counter ensures that 7 more checks should be made (resulting 7 seconds of waiting)
4. The http call is made on the 11th second (10 regular + 1 second of waiting)

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to having a "pausable timer". Once you have that, you can just use the `repeat` operator to re-run it whenever it completes:

```
somePausableTimer$.pipe(
    repeat(),
    switchMap(() => of('polling time'))
)
```

If you care about time precision, here's my take on "pausable timer" - I think it's about as precise as you can get with javascript, but without the performance penalty that comes with solutions such as "check the pause state every 10 ms":

```
import {delay, distinctUntilChanged, filter, map, mapTo, pairwise, repeat, 
    scan, startWith, switchMap, take, withLatestFrom} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {defer, fromEvent, NEVER, Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

function pausableTimer(timerSpan: number, isActive$: Observable<boolean>): Observable<boolean> {

    const activeState$ = isActive$.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        startWith(true, true),
        map(isActive => ({
            isActive,
            at: Date.now()
        }))
    );

    const pauseSpans$ = activeState$.pipe(
        pairwise(),
        filter(([,curr]) => curr.isActive),
        map(([prev, curr]) => curr.at - prev.at)
    );

    const accumulatedPauseSpan$ = pauseSpans$.pipe(
        scan((acc, curr) => acc += curr, 0)
    );

    return defer(() => {
        const startTime = Date.now();
        const originalEndTime = startTime + timerSpan;

        return activeState$.pipe(
            withLatestFrom(accumulatedPauseSpan$),
            switchMap(([activeState, accPause]) => {
                if (activeState.isActive) {
                    return of(true).pipe(
                        delay(originalEndTime - Date.now() + accPause)
                    );
                }
                else {
                    return NEVER;
                }
            }),
            take(1)
        );
    });
}
```

The function accepts a `timerSpan` in ms (in your case 10000) and an `isActive$` observable which emits `true`/`false` for resume/pause. So to put it together:

```
const isActive$ = fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(scan(acc => !acc, true)); // for example

pausableTimer(10000, isActive$).pipe(
    repeat(),
    switchMap(() => of('polling time'))
).subscribe();
```