# Does React rendering effects the setTimeout or setInterval function wrapped in a useRef and useRef is good way to achieve pause, stop, update question

Tags: javascript, reactjs, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to achieve the slider functionality, where I want to slider to move to the next question after every three seconds [this part is working fine]

Features i'm trying to achieve:

- OnMouseEnter: Timer stops, css animation stops(working)
- OnMouseleave: Start the timer from remaining time left
- OnClick: Change Question number to the selected items (working) and start animation

The issue is when I changed the question_number by onClick event, the next question start showing after every 1 seconds instead of 3 seconds. I think the problem is somehow with the React Re-rendering.

setSlider is simple useState has object:

```js
const [timeSlider, setTimeSlider] = useState({
  question_length: 4,
  question_number: 0,
  current_time: 0
});
```

I'm using useEffect to check the viewport width so react Re-render the components everytime, Viewport changes

I tried to store the Interval for timer in a react useRef. but still not working. Here is my code:

I use useRef, so I can Resume, Pause and updateNumber outSide where the first time setInterval started
`const interval = useRef(null);`

After EverySecond update the useState: Seconds

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setRemaining({
    start_time: Date.now(),
    stop_time: 0
  });
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
  }, 1000);
  pauseSlider();
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```

And when ever the seconds state changed, I make sure after every three seconds. question_number increased only when its less than 3

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (seconds === 3) {
    setSeconds(seconds => 0);
    setTimeSlider(prev => prev.question_number === 3 ? { ...timeSlider,
      question_number: 0
    } : { ...timeSlider,
      question_number: timeSlider.question_number + 1
    });
  }
}, [seconds]);
```

Below are the pause, resume and update function.

```js
function pauseSlider() {
  setSliderHover(true)
  setRemaining({
    start_time: 0,
    stop_time: Date.now()
  });
  clearInterval(interval.current);
}

function resumeSlider() {
  setSliderHover(false)
  setRemaining(prev => ({ ...prev,
    start_time: prev.stop_time,
    stop_time: 0
  }));
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
  }, 1000);
}

function updateNumber(num) {
  setSliderHover(false)
  setSeconds(0)
  setRemaining({
    start_time: 0,
    stop_time: 0
  });
  clearInterval(interval.current);
  interval.current = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
  }, 1000);
  setTimeSlider({ ...timeSlider,
    question_number: num
  });
}
```

The Problem could be in these functions, I tried to use setTimeout instead of setInterval same results.

Below is the picture of slider, so you have more clear idea what i'm trying to achieve.

[image: Demo of what i'm trying to achieve, the current question_number is 3 (questions starts from 0)]

Comment: I tried to achieve something similar using Rxjs you might benefit from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64711926/in-rxjs-how-to-pause-a-stream-of-data-and-continue-from-the-second-it-was-paused

Comment: when you clear interval, you need to clear `interval.current`. like this `return () => clearInterval(interval.current);`

Comment: @Layhout Thanks for the comment but I changed it and did get the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the JS, I used the GSAP for this here is my solution for it

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const ctx = gsap.context((self) => {
      TimelineRef.current = gsap.timeline({
        defaults: {
          repeat: -1,
          ease: "none",
        }
      })
        
      .to(".timerSlier_left", 
      {
        x: "0%",
        duration: 10,
        onRepeat: () => UpdateToNextQuestion(timeSlider),

      }
      )
    }, ContainerRef); // <- Scope!
    return () => ctx.revert(); // <- Cleanup!
  }, []);

  
  const [ remaining, setRemaining ] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    if ( isInViewport ){
      resumeSlider()
    }else{
      pauseSlider()
    }
  }, [ isInViewport ]);
  const UpdateToNextQuestion = () => {
    settimeSlider( prev => prev.question_number === 3 ? ({...prev, question_number: 0}) : ({...prev, question_number: prev.question_number+1}))
  }

  function pauseSlider(){
    console.log("stop slider")
    setSliderHover(true)
    TimelineRef.current.pause();
  }
  function resumeSlider(){
    setSliderHover(false)
    TimelineRef.current.resume();
  }
  function updateNumber(num){
    TimelineRef.current.restart();
    settimeSlider( timeSlider => ({ ...timeSlider, question_number: num }) );
    console.log("RESUMING")
    setSliderHover(false)
    TimelineRef.current.resume();
  }
```

I'm handing timeout functionality from GSAP timeline.