# How to create pause/resume timer which counts break time also, using RxJS

Tags: rxjs

I'm learning `rxjs` and would like to create a timer with pause, resume, and stop options. Also, I want it to count break time once I pushed the pause button.

I found this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dtnoif?file=index.ts but for me, it's hard to understand where should I put the break timer counter. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61865134/9632621) will be helpful.

Comment: should be helpful, thanks

Comment: This should be simple enough to modify: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676617/pause-an-interval-rxjs/64683558#64683558

Answer (score 0):

So, today I figured out how to implement this, but also have a bug to fix (the counter starts on `play` or `pause` in two seconds, and I don't know yet why).

Here is the source code

`index.ts`

```js
import { interval, fromEvent, merge, empty } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, mapTo, tap, startWith, scan } from "rxjs/operators";

// elem refs
const remainingLabel = document.getElementById("remaining");
const breakTimerDOM = document.getElementById("break-timer");
const pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");
const resumeButton = document.getElementById("play");
const stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");

// streams
const resume$ = fromEvent(resumeButton, "click").pipe(
  mapTo({ isCounting: true, isBlocked: false })
);
const pause$ = fromEvent(pauseButton, "click").pipe(
  mapTo({ isCounting: false, isBlocked: false })
);
const stop$ = fromEvent(stopButton, "click").pipe(
  mapTo({ isCounting: false, isBlocked: true, counter: 0, breakCounter: 0 }),
  tap(() => empty())
);

const timer$ = merge(resume$, pause$, stop$).pipe(
  startWith({
    counter: 0,
    breakCounter: 0,
    isCounting: false,
    isBlocked: true
  }),
  scan((state, curr) => ({ ...state, ...curr })),
  switchMap(state => {
    return !state.isBlocked
      ? interval(1000).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            const { isCounting, counter, breakCounter } = state;
            if (isCounting) {
              remainingLabel.innerHTML = counter.toString();
              state.breakCounter = 0;
              state.counter++;
            } else {
              breakTimerDOM.innerHTML = breakCounter.toString();
              state.breakCounter++;
            }
          })
        )
      : empty();
  })
);

timer$.subscribe();
```

`index.html`

```html
<h4>
    Time remaining: <span id="remaining">0</span>
</h4>
<h4>
    Break timer: <span id="break-timer">0</span>
</h4>
<button id="pause">
Pause
</button>
<button id="play">
Play
</button>
<button id="stop">
Stop
</button>
```

You can fork the source code from here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-7z6hab?file=index.ts .